# BarcodeScanning.getClient() is null

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode-scanner

````
```
````

in this line i have null.
private var scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient()

````
```


 class BarcodeAnalyzer(
        private val barcodeListener: (barcode: String) -> Unit
    ) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
    
    
        private var scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient()
    //    var scanner: BarcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(
    //        BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
    //            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_PDF417)
    //            .build()
    //    )
    
        @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError", "UnsafeOptInUsageError")
        override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
            val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
            if (mediaImage != null) {
    
                val height = mediaImage.height
                val width = mediaImage.width
    
                //Since in the end the image will rotate clockwise 90 degree
                //left -> top, top -> right, right -> bottom, bottom -> left
    
                //Top    : (far) -value > 0 > +value (closer)
                val c1x = (width * 0.125).toInt() + 150
                //Right  : (far) -value > 0 > +value (closer)
                val c1y = (height * 0.25).toInt() - 25
                //Bottom : (closer) -value > 0 > +value (far)
                val c2x = (width * 0.875).toInt() - 150
                //Left   : (closer) -value > 0 > +value (far)
                val c2y = (height * 0.75).toInt() + 25
    
                val rect = Rect(c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y)
    
                val ori = imageProxy.toBitmap()!!
                val crop = Bitmap.createBitmap(ori, rect.left, rect.top, rect.width(), rect.height())
                val rImage = crop.rotate(90F)
    
                val image: InputImage =
                    InputImage.fromBitmap(rImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
    
                // Pass image to the scanner and have it do its thing
                scanner.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                        // Task completed successfully
                        for (barcode in barcodes) {
                            barcodeListener(barcode.rawValue ?: "")
                            imageProxy.close()
                        }
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        // You should really do something about Exceptions
                        imageProxy.close()
                    }
                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                       imageProxy.close()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
   


when i run the project ,
i dont understand because i have this problem.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.merckers.asesorcajero, PID: 19722
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.internal.BarcodeScannerImpl com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.internal.zze.zza()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanning.getClient(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning@@18.0.0:1)
        at com.merckers.asesorcajero.features.scancamera2.BarcodeAnalyzer.<init>(BarcodeAnalyzer.kt:17)
        at com.merckers.asesorcajero.features.scancamera2.CamActivity.startCamera$lambda-4(CamActivity.kt:110)
        at com.merckers.asesorcajero.features.scancamera2.CamActivity.$r8$lambda$AyftUYVfi4HoXmISuYd5PCdW3Ws(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.merckers.asesorcajero.features.scancamera2.CamActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)

in others projects i have the same code and the same dependencies and working but in this project dont working and get a null references.

how can i resolve?

why i have this problem?
````

Comment: Edit your question and post the code where this crash occurs.

Comment: Remove all pictures and post all code as text. Behave!